# How do I iterate through a list I'm converting to a matrix from a string?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm very new to Python, and I'm currently going through the Matrix problem on Exercism. It's been pretty simple to this point, but I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to iterate through this list. I've been scouring through the web trying to figure it out on my own.

What I have to do is convert the string provided at the bottom to a matrix at the /n break, then to an integer so that I can use numpy to return either the rows or columns.

```
class Matrix(object):
def __init__(self, matrix_string):
        self.matrix = matrix_string.replace(' ', '').split('\n')
        self.temp = [int(i) for i in self.matrix[0]]

matrix = Matrix("1 2\n3 4")
print(matrix.temp)
```

I've gotten as far as converting the list, but now I need to return the entire list, not just a particular index as shown above, into a new temp list. That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: How about `self.temp = [[int(i) for i in row] for row in self.matrix]`? List-comprehensions can get quite unreadable with nested loops like this, so you could also consider a plain for-loop (or 2). And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Man, you're awesome. I tried to do something similar, but I ended up just nesting in way more confusion. After spending all of my free time one day learning how classes worked, I've been a bit frazzled. After looking at your answer, I understand now what I was doing wrong. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you could convert your list as you are doing there are some problems with the following line

`self.temp = [int(i) for i in self.matrix[0]]`

Consider converting "12 1" your result would be 1, 2, 1 rather than 12, 1

Instead you should split on newlines and then split each line on spaces (without replacing ' ' with '')

It would be a good exercise to try to do this by yourself but I will give you a hint and a solution for if you get stuck

Hint: initialize temp as an empty list first, then append lists to it one by one

---

More in depth hint approach: Initialize temp as an empty list. Split matrix on newlines. Append each line to temp, split on spaces.

solution:

```
self.temp = []
self.matrix = matrix_string.split('\n')
for element in self.matrix:
        self.temp.append(element.split(' '))
```

this can be simplified to one line of list comprehension
you can try that yourself or use the below

```
self.temp = [element.split(' ') for element in matrix_string.split('\n')]
```

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you! I ran into the exact problem you were describing while running the other tests against this script. I was able to convert the list properly this time, then convert the entire list into a new list as integers instead of strings with no more problems.